# how to create a new column by calculating a sum of column and dividing by a constant - pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, division, pyspark

I have to create a data frame by joining two other data frames
In the new data frame I am creating a new column by calculating a `sum(Col1)` and dividing with a number
I am trying below codes, neither of them work.

How do we handle dividing a column by a constant in pyspark

Try 1:

```
 df = df2.join(df1,cond,'inner).df1.groupby('category').withColumn('Amt', 
 (sum(df1('Col1'))/ 100))\
.withColumn('Amt1',(sum(df1(Col2))/ 100))\
.withColumn('Amt2',(sum(df1(Col3))/ 100))\
```

Try2:

```
(df1.agg(sum('Col1')))/lit(100)
```

Try3:

```
(df1.agg(sum('Col1')).div(100))
```

Error displayed:

Try 3: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'div'
Try 1 and 2 : 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'DataFrame' and 'int'

Comment: You did not add the "error displayed"

Comment: what is the purpose of adding a column with an aggregate if you do not use group by first? I mean, you have to decide on which values in the dataframe the sum has to be computed, I doubt you want to have all and add this value to each row. Also, would be much easier if you show input and expected output sample data.

Comment: I have added error messages and grouby clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `agg`. For giving the correct column name you can use `alias`:

```
df = df2.join(df1,cond,'inner').df1.groupby('category').agg( 
 (sum(df1('Col1'))/ 100).alias("Amt"),
 (sum(df1('Col2'))/ 100).alias("Amt1"),
 (sum(df1("Col3"))/ 100).alias("Amt2")
)
```